# window.getSelection() not working in popup window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple react component that modifies the content I want to copy to clipboard. The `onCopy` callback works well when it is on the main window. However, when I move to a popup window, the selection is empty (`isCollapsed===true`) and `selection.getRangeAt(0);` throws an error.

How can I get the text selection also in a **popup window**?

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<...> {

    public render(){
      return (
        <div onCopy={this.onCopy}>
          <a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.text}</a>
        </div>
      )
    }

    private onCopy = (e: React.ClipboardEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      if (!selection) {
        return;
      }
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const copiedContents = range.cloneContents();
      // Case unfurled component partially selected
      const url = this.props.url
      e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', url);
      e.clipboardData.setData(
        'text/html',
        `<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`,
      );
   };
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Window object refers to the main window. That's why the selection wasn't working in the popup. To make it work we need to **use the window object we create when opening the popup window**.

However, the problem with the clipboard data remains (I opened a dedicated question since it is a different problem [ClipboardData not setting data in popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74137253/clipboarddata-not-setting-data-in-popup-window))